# jQuery ui datepicker - Clear beforeShowDay property

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a "select menu" that then populates my jQuery ui datepicker with the dates that are available to book.

Now what I'd like to do is when you change the select option, The beforeShowDay is cleared, To then populate it with the new data.

Is there a function that clears this when an event change is triggered? I've had a google and not really seen much.

Hopefully someone has come across this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just fire the destroy on the *datepicker* field and re-attach the *datepicker* without the `beforeShowDay` option.

For example, if your datepicker is attached to a textbox called "*txtDate*", then

```
$('#txtDate').datepicker("destroy");
```

Then, re-attach the datepicker without `beforeShowDay` option:

```
$('#txtDate').datepicker({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
```

Put the above inside your `change` event handler of the `select`.

Comment: Excellent. That should do it quite nicely, Thank you @abhitalks